# casperjs issue downloading csv file

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to download the following csv file using casperjs

```
var casper = require('casper').create({});
casper.start('http://69.50.252.196/');
casper.then(function(){
    this.download('http://69.50.252.196/download.csv', 'downloaded.csv');
});
casper.run(function() {
    this.exit();
});
```

**download.csv**

```
إختبار  Arabic
آزمایشی Persian
测试  Chinese
測試  Chinese
испытание   Russian
परीक्षा Hindi
δοκιμή  Greek, Modern (1453-)
테스트 Korean
טעסט    Yiddish
テスト Japanese
பரிட்சை Tamil
```

but the downloaded file always corrupted and got corrupted characters

**downloaded.csv**

```
"%.*('1 Arabic" 
"2E'ج4ج Persian
Kص  Chinese
,f  Chinese
8A?KB0=85   Russian
*0@M7> Hindi
´؟؛¹¼®  Greek"   Modern (1453-)"
"L¤¸    Korean" 
"طâلط   Yiddish"    
"ئ¹ب    Japanese"   
"ھ°؟ںحڑب    Tamil"
```

Help please, i cant use child_process or wget or curl
file must be downloaded using casperjs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after researching casperjs modules solution found !
the issue due to base64encode of data in addition to handling binary data

Workaround till fix:
I removed the encoding function and modified open file flag for wb to w

**OLD casper.js**

```
fs.write(targetPath, cu.decode(this.base64encode(url, method, data)), 'wb');
```

**New casper.js**

```
fs.write(targetPath, this.base64encode(url, method, data), 'w');
```

**OLD clientutils.js**

```
return this.encode(this.getBinary(url, method, data));
```

**New clientutils.js**

```
return this.getBinary(url, method, data);
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a PhantomJS bug. (I just upgraded from 1.9.0 to 1.9.2 to be sure: I'd hoped [this bug report](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11277) might have meant it was fixed in 1.9.1.)

However it does work with SlimerJS. When I run with:

```
casperjs --engine=slimerjs test.js
```

I get a 356 byte file, exactly as I do with wget (and it displays as UTF-8, correctly). With PhantomJS as the CasperJS engine I get a 177 byte file, that does not display anything useful.